# How to generate an ID card using Webform in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

We have explored Drupal in terms of generation of a PDF from the results of a Webform.

Can we also create an ID card (e.g. paper size CR80 i.e. 2.13 x 3.38 in) using the same functionality? The paper size mentioned above could not be found in the list of paper sizes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't mention how you are generating the .pdf

Comment: Additional info: To generate PDF, WEbform@PDF module enabled. We are using the standard Drupal functionality of 'Generate PDF' found under 'Webform' tab.